# Is to secure to pass an eloquent collection in Livewire parameters?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I want to know if it is secure to pass eloquent collections in a Livewire component.

```
@livewire('dashboard', ['modelCollection' => App\Models\User::find(1)])
```

Is there any threat to the database because we are then exposing the database information? Is it secure?

Comment: Yes it is, because Livewire is rendered server side. So, the model is only available on the server. However, if you expose something else in your component it could become a security issue.

Comment: Curious why you think this is exposing the database information. A Model shouldn't contain anything like that... If you do `dd(App\Models\User::find(1))`, you'll see all the information about that Model, and the specific row you're retrieving, but no database information (i.e. schema, user, password, etc.). Also, `find(1)` doesn't return a `Collection`, but rather a single `User` instance or `null`, so calling this `modelCollection` is not a great idea, as you might _think_ it is a `Collection` and try to use Collection methods on it, which will trigger an error.